# I get this error:- Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch even after I registered the URI in Google Gmail API OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-console

Hello there I'm a newbie to programming. I was going to authenticate to Gmail API using oauth2 Authentication and I forgot to set the redirect URI at the first place. Then I registered it but I still get the below error code and I watched dozens of youtube videos but couldn't find an error in my code this is the second day I'm trying it. It still shows :-redirect_uri: http://localhost:8080/ in the consent screen like this:-

[image: Please check this image]

And this is my **main.py file**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import base64
from email.message import EmailMessage

import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import time

from Google import Create_Service

def gmail_send_message():
    """Create and send an email message
    Print the returned  message id
    Returns: Message object, including message id

    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
    """
    creds = 'oauthkey.json' 

    scopes = ['https://mail.google.com/']

    mlist = open("mail list.txt", "r")

    #cred = google.auth.default()

    service = Create_Service(creds, 'gmail' ,'v1', scopes)
    message = EmailMessage()

    message.set_content('Hi for checking purposes only ') 

    message['from'] = 'emma.adcreaive@gmail.com'

    message['Subject'] = 'System Generated'

    for mail in mlist:
        message['to'] = mail
        # encoded message
        encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()

        create_message = {
            'raw': encoded_message
        }
        # pylint: disable=E1101
        send_message = (service.users().messages().send
                             (userId="me", body=create_message).execute())
        print(F'Message Id: {send_message["id"]}')
        return send_message
        time.delay("12")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gmail_send_message()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to go to [google developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) for your project and add the redirect uri to the project you must set it to this exactly

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Credentials on the left -> edit your client add the redirect uri above.

[image]

See: [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

Comment: This no longer works in 2023: Invalid Redirect: must use a domain that is a valid top private domain

Comment: This works fine in 2023 as long as your app is still in the testing phase.  Once your app is in production and or needs verification then you will need to use a domain registered by you.    Localhost works fine for development, testing, and single user apps.

Comment: Google now prevents using localhost or similar on this form, at least for me. I just tried it. Maybe it works still for others.

Comment: Why not open a new question with your code I would be happy to take a look.   Localhost works fine for testing locally